# how can i solve this nonlinear problem?

Tags: differential-equations, schwartz-distributions

let be the differential equation in dimension $ n > 3 $ or $ n =3 $

$$ -\Delta u =|grau|^{2}u $$   (1)

with the constraint that the vector  'u' $ |u|=1 $

then how could i prove that the unitary vector $ u = \frac{x}{|x|} $ with $ x=(x1,x2,...xn) $

solves the PDE above ??

i.e  'u' is a Weak solution to the PDE (1)  in the Unit sphere U

how could i if possible use 'variational principles' to solve this kind of equation ?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to search the literature? The keywords "harmonic map" and "liquid crystals" seem like good ones to get you started.

Comment: could someone give me a hand ? please :( to solve this problem